# numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have a database and I'm required to make a make a bar plot of the na_count. However, I'm trying to make a list of both na_count keys & values, but this message is coming up "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ny = pd.read_csv("311_Service_Requests_from_2010_to_Present.csv")
na_count = ny[ny.columns].isna().sum()
dic_keys = list(na_count.keys())
dic_values = list(na_count.values())

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_258/3214600081.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dic_values = list(na_count.values())

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

the na_count:

```
Unique Key                            0
Created Date                          0
Closed Date                         380
Agency                                0
Agency Name                           0
Complaint Type                        1
Descriptor                          975
Location Type                         1
Incident Zip                        428
Incident Address                   7825
Street Name                        7825
Cross Street 1                     8763
Cross Street 2                     8838
Intersection Street 1             57161
Intersection Street 2             57241
Address Type                        488
City                                429
Landmark                          64865
Facility Type                       376
Status                                1
Due Date                              1
Resolution Description                1
Resolution Action Updated Date      369
Community Board                       1
Borough                               1
X Coordinate (State Plane)          570
Y Coordinate (State Plane)          570
Park Facility Name                    1
Park Borough                          1
School Name                           1
School Number                         1
School Region                         1
School Code                           1
School Phone Number                   1
School Address                        1
School City                           1
School State                          1
School Zip                            1
School Not Found                      1
School or Citywide Complaint      64904
Vehicle Type                      64904
Taxi Company Borough              64904
Taxi Pick Up Location             64904
Bridge Highway Name               64843
Bridge Highway Direction          64843
Road Ramp                         64852
Bridge Highway Segment            64852
Garage Lot Name                   64904
Ferry Direction                   64904
Ferry Terminal Name               64904
Latitude                            570
Longitude                           570
Location                            570
```

Comment: no images. use text

Comment: could you please post your code so we can see what you are referring to?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code _as text_, formatted in a [code block](/help/formatting)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check again, I added the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do we know what is the data in `csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na_count returns a `pandas.Series`. This means it has an attribute called `.values` which contains the underlying `numpy.ndarray` with the data. You are "calling" an already initiated numpy array, which of course does not work since it is not a function.
For example consider:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10)
a()
```

This will raise your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I guess what you are looking for is this:

```
pd.Series(a).to_dict().values()
```

> I have a database and I'm required to make a make a bar plot of the na_count. However, I'm trying to make a list of both na_count keys & values

If your goal is to make a countplot, you do not need to get the values and keys as a list. Keep the dataframe as is and use sns.countplot: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. I used plt.bar(dic_keys, na_count.values, color ='maroon',  width = 0.4) to solve the problem.

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted solution then.

Comment: thank you Leo, I just did. bare with me a new user.